# roxygen2 equivalent for python

Tags: python, roxygen2

I want to create some documentation for a package written in python.

When I create a package in R, roxygen2 does that for me.

Is there a python/pandas equivalent?

Comment: Sphinx is perfect for this job

Comment: Sphinx is the right answer, but I can't help but note that roxygen2 is based on [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/index.html), and Doxygen can work on Python.  This implies that another possible answer is Doxygen.

Comment: Do note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."  However, I'm not voting to close this question as I think probably won't "attract opinionated answers and spam."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/), it can parse your source code and generate module documentation from function docstrings.

Specifically, the `autodoc` features: http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html